# SQL Server connection problem with SQLCMD command

Tags: sql-server

I have a large database script. Now I am trying to execute that script with SQLCMD command. But after putting the command I am having error: Here is the SQLCMD command:

```
sqlcmd -S MachineName\DatabaseName -i "D:/sqlscript.sql"
```

Here is the error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SQL Server
> Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
> [xFFFFFFFF]. . Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
> : Login timeout expired. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for
> SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred
> while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or
> not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
> configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
> Server Books Online..

Can you please help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think database is a separate parameter. Read the docs on sqlcmd...

Comment: `-S` should be `-S MachineName\InstanceName`, you probably want to include `use DatabaseName;` at the beginning of your .sql file... which should also be `D:\sqlscript.sql` since Windows doesn't permit forward slashes `/` in pathnames.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning probably best to just use the `-D` parameter for that

Comment: @Charlieface you mean the _`-D` Interprets the server name provided to -S as a DSN instead of a hostname. For more information, see DSN Support in sqlcmd and bcp in Connecting with sqlcmd_ [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#command-line-options)? Or `-d`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning whoops no meant lower-case `-d`. Argh that is so Unix, most Windows args are case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

`-S MachineName\DatabaseName` is incorrect.

The bit after `\` is supposed to be the instance name, not the database name. For instance names to work you need SQL Browser to be running on that machine also. If you have a default instance then you should remove it completely and just use the machine name.

The database name meanwhile goes in a separate parameter `-d` (lower-case).

For further reference see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16).